# Wget In Parralel. What can I do to improve the download speed?

Tags: unix, tcp, wget, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a web crawler using wget.  The crawler only fetches the homepages of subdomains, and I'm running it like this:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 800 -I {} wget {} --max-redirect 3 --tries=1 --no-check-certificate --read-timeout=95 --no-dns-cache --connect-timeout=60 --dns-timeout=45 -q
```

When I run that, I only get speeds of ~5mbps.  The server I'm crawling from has a 100mbps bandwidth connecton and can download files from individual sites at 20mbps+.

What can I do to speed up this crawler?

Note: 
The nameserver is Google DNS (8.8.8.8)

I have these ulimits

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 254243
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 254243
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

and have tried these speed tweaks:

```
echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
echo 5 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
echo 1024 65535 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```